# Custom module creates 'Invalid template file in module' error

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module, override-block

I wanted to have a product's brand name shown next to it's product name, so I created a module for this. I extended the Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title block in order to obtain the brand name and use this in the template.

The module works as expected, but for some reason my system.log becomes filled by the following error:
**main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'title.phtml' in module: 'Kyegil_ProductBrand' block's name: 'page.title'**

What have I left out here? Why I'm I getting this error?

**etc/di.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title" type="Kyegil\ProductBrand\Block\Html\Title" />
</config>
```

**Block/Html/Title.php**

```
<?php
namespace Kyegil\ProductBrand\Block\Html;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Title extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title
{

protected $_coreRegistry = null;
protected $_product = null;
protected $_brand = '';


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;

    $this->_product = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product');

    if(is_object($this->_product)) {
        $this->_brand = $this->_product->getData('brand');
    }

    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}


public function getBrand()
{
    if (is_array($this->_brand)) {
        return implode(", ", $this->_brand);
    }
    return strval($this->_brand);
}

}
```

**view/frontend/templates/html/title.phtml**

```
<?php

$cssClass = $block->getCssClass() ? ' ' . $block->getCssClass() : '';
$title = '';
if (trim($block->getPageHeading())) {
    $title = '<span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper" ' .  $block->getAddBaseAttribute() . '>'
        . $block->escapeHtml($block->getPageHeading()) . '</span>';
}
?>
<?php if ($title): ?>
<div class="page-title-wrapper<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $cssClass; ?>">
    <?php if($block->getBrand()):?>
        <h2><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getBrand()); ?></span></h2>
    <?php endif;?>
    <h1 class="page-title"
        <?php if ($block->getId()): ?> id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getId();?>" <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($block->getAddBaseAttributeAria()): ?>
            aria-labelledby="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAddBaseAttributeAria(); ?>"
        <?php endif; ?>>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $title ?>
    </h1>
    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**UPDATE**: My module doesn't have a layout xml, but even if I make one and change the template to eg 'custom.phtml', it doesn't make any difference.
A new entry is still created in my system.log asking for the 'title.phtml', funnily enough every time I load a page in the admin area.
This could be a clue though, since the only mentioning of 'page.title'  that I can find anywhere is in the default.xml of the Magento_Backend module.

Comment: Where you call `title.phtml`? Please show the code.

Comment: Clear the log file and cache and after that reload the page and see if you have a new log with the same log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by overwriting the _toHtml() method of my block so that it defaults to the old template file. I reckon this is necessary to avoid conflict with other modules using \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title.

**in Block/Html/Title.php**:

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    $this->setModuleName($this->extractModuleName('Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title'));
    return parent::_toHtml();
}
```

Then I specified a template file in view/frontend/layout/default.xml for my own use, as Sohel Rana recommended:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Kyegil_ProductBrand::html/title.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

The module works as before, and I'm no longer having critical entries in my system.log.

Answer (score 1):

Add following line into your override class

```
protected $_template = 'Magento_Theme::html/title.phtml';
```

So your class looks like

```
class Title extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title
{

    protected $_coreRegistry = null;
    protected $_product = null;
    protected $_brand = '';

    protected $_template = 'Magento_Theme::html/title.phtml';

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;

        $this->_product = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product');

        if(is_object($this->_product)) {
            $this->_brand = $this->_product->getData('brand');
        }

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    public function getBrand()
    {
        if (is_array($this->_brand)) {
            return implode(", ", $this->_brand);
        }
        return strval($this->_brand);
    }

}
```

OR

Kyegil/ProductBrand/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Theme::html/title.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I see that I've forgotten to explicitly call the module's template file. For some reason it was loaded anyway.
But the template should be 'Kyegil_ProductBrand::html/title.phtml', right, as the template is part of the module..

Comment: By adding the default.xml I'm able to rename the template, however this has no effect on my log entries, which, oddly enough, are created every time I load or refresh a page in the admin area.

Comment: Did you cleared cache?

Comment: yes, cache cleared, tried with different themes etc.

Comment: Wired? It tested code. Working fine for me.

Comment: Have you visited your admin area, and then checked your system.log afterwards?

Comment: Yes, it's working fine. Not sure why frontend template missing for admin area for you.